# Error when running a C++ service node using a custom srv in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow these two tutorials to create a node that provides a ROS2 service using a custom .srv:

- https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces/
- https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Service-And-Client/

Following the steps in the tutorials, I've created the following packages:

- `transform_service_srv` - contains the custom srv type.
- `transform_service` - contains the server.

Both packages build using colcon with no warnings.

I can examine the srv as follows:

```
$ ros2 srv show transform_service_srv/srv/TransformPose 
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped source_pose
string target_frame
---
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped target_pose
bool success
```

Attempting to run the service node results in the following error:

```
$ ros2 run transform_service transform_service 
/home/spragunr/ros2_ws/install/transform_service/lib/transform_service/transform_service: symbol lookup error: /home/spragunr/ros2_ws/install/transform_service_srv/lib/libtransform_service_srv__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN13geometry_msgs3msg24typesupport_fastrtps_cpp31max_serialized_size_PoseStampedERbm
```

I don't have any experience building ROS2 C++ nodes, so I don't know where to begin debugging this. I've attempted this in both dashing and foxy and the result is exactly the same for both.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355652/error-when-running-a-c++-service-node-using-a-custom-srv-in-ros2/) by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2020-06-23**:
Can you please post your actual code?

**Comment by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) on 2020-06-24**:
Here is a github repository with both packages:

https://github.com/spragunr/transform_service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the answer here: #q326008.

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2020-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0